# Replace/remove String between two character

Tags: java, string

I want to remove a string that is between two characters and also the characters itself , lets say for example:

i want to replace all the occurrence of the string between "#?" and ";" and remove it with the characters.

From this

> ```
> "this #?anystring; is  #?anystring2jk; test"
> ```

To This

> ```
> "this is test"
> ```

how could i do it in java ?

Comment: I removed the android tag since is has is not android-specific at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use regex:

```
myString.replaceAll("#\?.*?;", "");
```

Answer (score 21):

@computerish your answer executes with errors in Java. The modified version works.

```
myString.replaceAll("#\\?.*?;", "");
```

The reason being the ? should be escaped by 2 backslashes else the JVM compiler throws a runtime error **illegal escape character**. **You escape ? characters using the backslash .However, the backslash character() is itself a special character, so you need to escape it as well with another backslash.**

Comment: I don't understand how the answer by computerish has 2 votes. Is it fixed or what???.

Comment: Can you help me understand the second ?.  I am trying to replace everything between a : and a \n and ":.*\n" is working for me.  What does the second ? do?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the now accepted one does not work.

Answer (score 5):

[`string.replaceAll(start+".*"+end, "")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

is the easy starting point.  You might have to deal with [greediness](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) of the regex operators, however.