# How to replace a block of text using regex and java

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have the same problem, but I need to get:

```
---- comment 3;comment 2;comment 1
```

From:

```
* (20-01-2012 12:53) : ---- comment 3<br/>* (20-01-2012 12:50) : comment 2<br/>* (20-01-2012 12:50) : comment 1
```

Which means my code should be:

```
string.replaceAll("\\*?.*?:", ";")
```

Correct?

But this is replacing everything from the first * to the last : so I'm getting:

```
comment 1
```

as the result. Help!

Linked from [Replace/remove String between two character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756657/replace-remove-string-between-two-character/8938079#8938079)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myString = myString.replaceAll("\\*\\s+\\(.*?\\)\\s+:\\s+", "").replaceAll("<br/>", ";");`

It works I've tried.First replaceAll replaces the `* (date/time) :` prefix from lines and second replaceAll replaces `<br/>`s with `;`s.

Comment: ok looks like ALMOST the result i'm looking for, but i changed it to: `code`remark = remark.replaceAll("(\\*\\s+\\(.*?\\)\\s+)(.*?):\\s+", "");
        remark = remark.replaceAll("<br/>", ";");`code`

Answer (score 1):

In the previous answer it used `#?` as a delimiter. Here you write `\*?` which means match `*` literally or nothing. `.*?` will then match anything until `:`. That means multiple replacements will occur and strip anything until a colon (included). You should have multiple `;` in your replaced string.

The pattern I see is:

```
* (...) : ... comment 1<br/>
```

With `<br/>`optional.

Thus try a regex like:

```
\* \([^)]*\) : ((?:.*?)comment \d+)(?:<br/>)?
```

Note that `(?: ... )` makes the parenthesized regex non-grouping. You can check the result at http://rubular.com/r/orViHMJEMr

The regex provided here allows you to get the comments.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern_string = "\\* \\([^)]*\\) : ((?:.*?)comment \\d+)(?:<br/>)?";
        String input_string = "* (20-01-2012 12:53) : ---- comment 3<br/>* (20-01-2012 12:50) : comment 2<br/>* (20-01-2012 12:50) : comment 1";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern_string);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input_string);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this indeed works but damn! this to me is an overkill using groups, then optional groups - it took me a while to understand what you were doing :) nevertheless +1 from me

Comment: The regex might seem complicated but I don't think it is. The group allows us to get what we need. The non-grouping is not necessary but I used it like some kind of optimization. The rest of the pattern has the same structure as the input we want to match. The `[^)]* is also some kind of optimization. I could have done `.*?` instead.

Comment: umm, ok, @lkuty, but the pattern is <br/> * (...) : ... 
With <br/>optional.  and comment is not fixed, i just used comment1 ,2,3 as examples, so this is looking a little bit more complicated than i anticipated ...

Comment: Then the problem was not clearly specified. Anyway the regex is adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to replace `<br/>* (20-01-2012 12:50) :` with `;`.

A good matching regex could be:

```
(<br/>)\*\s*\(.*?\)\s*:\s*
```

The matching portion should be replaced with `;`.

For the beginning part, the regex should be:

```
^\*\s*\(.*?\)\s*:\s*
```

which should be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: almost, but was adding an extra ; before the first comment as well... hmm, think @Ademiban is the closest to what i actually wanted to happen... thanks for the effort tho! :)